# Centered wrapper with a side bar

Tags: html, css

Lets say we have a simple element that contains mostly everything in the website. We apply a width and set margin auto so its centered. Now we have two empty slots on both side of the page. How could I place a div on either side that is the width of this empty gap so I can use that area.

I made a small demo of the problem https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOUH4J4FO9I2
[image]

What I am trying to get working.
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:lime;
}

.leftbar{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="leftbar">
    <p>This is the problem. The width of this should extend to the left side of the green wrapper without making the green wrapper uncentered. This should be resized when the screen width is changed.</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Example simple wrapper</p>
<p>Setting a width and margin auto</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Grid can do that

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  background: red;
}

main {
  background: lightgreen;
  align-self: start;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <aside class="sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime obcaecati quidem, delectus quia aspernatur aliquid voluptate quasi consequatur placeat officiis, dolor vitae similique porro at?</aside>
  <main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem4 </main>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```